# hasattr to check whether a function has an attribute

Tags: python, oop

I was just looking at the `hasattr` method which takes in an object as a argument.

To check the "everything is an object" theory. I made a user defined function with an attribute `"name"`, but it returns `False`. The code which I wrote was:

```
def trial():
    name = "james"

hasattr(trial, "name")
```

Does this mean that functions are not objects? I would appreciate it if someone can help we figure this out.

Comment: The function is an object, but `name` is not an attribute. `name` is a variable that is created when the `trial()` function is run. Functions are objects, and do have attributes, but local variables are not them.

Comment: For example if you add `trial.name = 'James'` between the function definition and the check you'll see it is true.

Comment: You don't have a function with an attribute `name`.

Comment: Can you give an example of function having attributes.Also, I was under the impression that  attributes are nothing but properties of the object. So why are variables not an attribute.

Comment: @SahibSingh variables are names produced as a result of processing the procedure defined in the function.

Comment: `print(dir(trial))` to see the function's attributes. For instance, the function's name is in an attribute called `trial.__name__`

Comment: @jonrsharpe i did the trial.name change . Still False.

Comment: But did you do that inside or outside the function? If inside, you'll have to run the function at least once to see it take effect.

Comment: @khelwood okay understood that. So is there any way i can make name an attribute of the function.

Comment: @SahibSingh Yes, write `trial.name='James'`, just as jonrsharpe told you.

Comment: got what you are saying. @jonrsharpe

Comment: @khelwood @jonrsharpe if variables are not attributes. then while defining a class if i define a variable `name`  why does it treat it as an attribute?

Comment: That's just how Python language is defined. The rules governing how the class body is semantically interpreted are different than the rules for function bodies..

Answer (score 2):

Functions *are* objects, but what you have created is a function with a *local variable* `name`, which is *not* an attribute of that function. Let's inspect the function code:

```
>>> trial.__code__.co_varnames
('name',)
```

As you can see, `name` is indeed a local variable of the function.

However, attributes can still be defined on functions:

```
>>> def trial():
...     name = "james"
... 
>>> trial.foo = 'bar'
>>> hasattr(trial, 'foo')
True
>>> getattr(trial, 'foo')
'bar'
```

The way to assign an attribute to a function is by saying `<func>.<attr_name> = <attr_value>`, just like for any other other object that allows for it.

(not saying this is necessarily the best way of achieving the desired result, but just as a demo that it is possible)

Answer (score 1):

A function in Python is indeed an object but local variables in a function are not a property of it.

Try adding this at the end of your code:

```
>>> trial.__dir__()
```

It will show you all the properties of the function you defined - and you're accessing a property of the function object.

You can even add properties to the function object if you want, though you have to be careful as to not overwrite an existing property. Try this:

```
>>> trial.foo = 'bar'
>>> dir(trial)  # Equivalent to trial.__dir__(). 'foo' is now in the list.
>>> hasattr(trial, 'foo')
>>> print(trial.foo)
```

When your code is executing, the function becomes something tangible from the moment it is defined but the variables in it are ephemeral in the sense that they are values stored in memory only for the duration of the function execution (i.e. when you call it) and are gone after it finishes. It's actually a bit more complicated than that, with garbage collection in the mix, but from a simple perspective, that's pretty much what happens.